# missing keys in $_POST

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get some form data from POST method.

Here's the code of form -

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

<input type="hidden" value="15" name="ad_id"> 

  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="block">

    <tbody><tr>

      <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

      <td align="right">all fields are required</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>

      <td align="center"></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top" width="150"><label for="name">Advertisement Name</label>

      *</td>

      <td><input type="text" size="45" value="Banner" id="name" name="name">

        e.g Home Banner</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top"><label for="placement">Advertisement Placement</label></td>

      <td><select id="placement" name="placement">
```

Wide Skyscrapper 160 x 600

```
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top"><label for="code">Advertisement Code</label></td>

      <td><textarea rows="5" cols="45" id="code" name="code"></textarea></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>Status</td>

      <td><label>

        <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="status">

        Active</label>

        <label>

          <input type="radio" value="0" name="status">

        Inactive</label></td>

    </tr>        
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="banner_uploaded" id="banner_uploaded">
    <tr>
     <td>For Country - </td>
     <td>
      <select id="country" name="country">         
 <option>Not posting all the names of country</option>
        </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                              <td><label for="Scheduling">Valid From </label></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="" id="date-from" name="date-from"> Format : dd/mm/yyyy:hh/mm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
                              <td><label for="Scheduling">Valid Till </label></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="" id="date-to" name="date-to"> Format : dd/mm/yyyy:hh/mm</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>

      <td align="right"><input type="submit" onclick="return validate_ad_form(add_adv)" value="Update Advertisement" class="button" name="update"></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody></table>

</form>
```

But I am getting $_POST['code'] empty when I am passing HTML code through it.

When I pass plain text, it works fine.

When I printed $_POST [i.e. used - print_r($_POST) ], I got the following output -

Array ( [ad_id] => 15 [name] => Banner [placement] => ad_468x60 [code] => [status] => 1 [banner_uploaded] => 1 [country] => IN [date-from] => [date-to] => [update] => Update Advertisement )

Please be known, I haven't entered the 'date-from','date-to' fields.

I have entered  on purpose as StackOverflow don't allow me to post images!

People,any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The HTML code I am passing - <a href="www.example.info"><img src="example.jpg" /></a>

Comment: Are you using a framework? Perhaps it could be stripping HTML from the POST variable?

Comment: @col. shrapnel ..... i cannot understand you.

@ethier the original script is ClipBucket (it can called be CMS too).Have checked sources, found nothing :-(

Comment: I have used the same code you've provided, posted the same string you've provided and it works just fine. I've just added print_r( $POST ) and the bottom of the code. When I check the page source, it shows me exactly what I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're `print_r()` is being displayed in a brower. If you've got HTML in your POST data, those tags will be interested as HTML when you dump the data back out. You'll have to force the output into plaintext mode (`header('Content-type: text/plain);`), or run the fields which can have HTML in them through `htmlspecialchars()` to escape the < and > characters.

If you view the source of the page you're doing the `print_r()` on, I suspect you'll see the HTML tags there. If you've only tested with that `example.jpg` image, you wouldn't see anything, because that image most likely doesn't exist, so it won't render, and then the `<a>` tag has nothing to underline and won't show up either.